# Looping lists in tandem every nth iteration

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and am having trouble figuring out how to get a loop scenario to work. Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> b = range(5)
>>> b
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if i == 0 or it's the fourth iteration:
        print a[i] and a value from b
    else print a[i]
```

the output i'm shooting for would be something like this

```
0 0
1
2
3
4 1
5
6
7
8 2
```

etc....

Does anyone have a good solution for something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the [modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) to determine if it's the *fourth* value:

```
>>> a = range(20)
>>> b = range(5)
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...   if i%4==0:
...     print a[i], b[i/4]
...   else:
...     print a[i]
...
0 0
1
2
3
4 1
5
6
7
8 2
9
10
11
12 3
13
14
15
16 4
17
18
19
>>>
```

Comment: Wow, this is great. I have never used the % operator outside of string formatting. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter to track the iteration number:

```
 counter = 1
 for i in range(len(a)):
     if i == 0 or counter == 4:
         print(a[i], b[i/4])
         counter = 1
     else:
         print(a[i])
     counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to get a list of items with their index:

```
for i, j in enumerate(a):
    if i == 0 or i%4 == 0:
        print j, b[i/4]
    else:
        print j
```

Where `i` is the index and `j` is the item itself.